# Каков предел возможностей maven без плагинов?

Tags: java, maven

Проблема, с которой я столкнулся при обучении maven - очень мало качественного материала, особенно такого, чтобы можно было достигнуть понимания при использовании на практике на реальных примерах.

Во многих примерах, что я видел, используются плагины. Я ничего не имею против плагинов, но для того, чтобы pom.xml был прост в поддерживаемости, каждый плагин должен быть добавлен по рациональной причине.

В учебных примерах я видел, что в maven добавляются плагины для таких примитивных нужд, как сборка JAR-файла. Maven без плагинов настолько примитивен, что даже не может откомпилировать Java (добавляется maven-compiler) и собрать JAR-файл? Что вообще maven может без плагинов?

Comment: Плагин на сборку по большей части нужен, что бы указать дополнительные параметры. Без блока плагинов основную часть занимает блок с зависимостями и немного описания проекта/модуля (название, используемая версия java и пр)

Comment: Плагины нужны для того,чтобы вы могли кастомизировать ваши lifecycle. К примеру? вы можете выбрать какое имя задать жар файлу, где искать web.xml, какой версией компилировать тесты/код, выполнять тесты или нет и т.д/ Список плагинов вы можете посмотреть, используя команду mvn help:effective-pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что вообще maven может без плагинов?

Ничего. Maven — это система, которая позволяет плагинам взаимодействовать между собой, не более.

На официальном сайте [написано](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html):

> Maven is - at its heart - a plugin execution framework; all work is done by plugins...
>
> *Maven — в своей основе — есть платформа исполнения плагинов; всю работу делают плагины.*

Плагины будут загружаться и выполняться даже если их не указывать в POM, т.к. есть плагины, которые по-умолчанию привязаны к стандартным фазам и целям сборки (см. [Plugin Bindings for default Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.2/maven-core/default-bindings.html)).

Так, на фазе compile будет выполняться maven-compiler-plugin. При этом явно прописывать его в POM нужно только если требуется внести изменения в настройки (использовать конкретную версию плагина, задать флаг для компилятора).

Преимуществом такой архитектуры построения Maven является то, что плагины крайне [слабо зависят](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) друг от друга. Разные команды могут совершенно отдельно друг от друга работать над компиляцией, тестированием, либо сборкой ресурсов. Побочные преимущества: ошибка в отдельном плагине не затронет другие, можно перейти на новую версию отдельного плагина.

> Что вообще maven может без плагинов?

Из вышесказанного следует, что говорить о Maven без плагинов не совсем корректно, т.к. Maven есть не что иное как крайне простая система, которая передает всю работу плагинам.

Имеет смысл говорить о сочетании Maven + плагины по-умолчанию, т.е. о работе без сторонних плагинов.

> Maven без плагинов настолько примитивен, что даже не может откомпилировать Java (добавляется maven-compiler) и собрать JAR-файл?

Maven с плагинами по-умолчанию вполне способен откомпилировать Java.

Проведем эксперимент с простым Hello World!:

Создадим проект следующей структуры:

```
src
    main
        java
            HelloWorld.java
pom.xml
```

В pom.xml пропишем только описание проекта:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</project>
```

В `HelloWorld.java` пропишем код:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
```

Теперь соберем проект:

```
mvn install
```

Дождемся успешного выполнения (`BUILD SUCCESS ...`) и запустим программу

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="HelloWorld"
```

Если все будет хорошо, программа запустится и покажет сообщение «Hello, World!». Это будет говорить о том, что плагины по-умолчанию способны без каких-либо дополнительных настроек компилировать код.

Какие именно плагины (координаты и версии) используются по-умолчанию можно просмотреть с помощью команды `mvn help:effective-pom`

> Я ничего не имею против плагинов, но для того, чтобы pom.xml был прост в поддерживаемости, каждый плагин должен быть добавлен по рациональной причине.

Это очень правильный подход. Но нужно понимать, что:

- стандартные плагины используются, даже если их не указывать;
- явное указание стандартного плагина нужно тогда и только тогда, когда в поведение по-умолчанию вносятся какие-то изменения (например, указывается более ранняя/поздняя версия Java).

Comment: Прямо от души всё объяснили и наглядно показали, у меня даже нет слов...  Благодарю Вас за замечательный ответ!

Comment: @БоковГлеб Пожалуйста! Удачи Вам!